# fullcalendar - resize calendar on window resize 

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar ([fullcalendar by adam shaw](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/))

I am wondering what I would need to do so that my fullcalendar dynamically changes size depending on the size of the browser window? I have looked into his 'render' function a little bit but have been having trouble figuring this out.

(ie, when a user resizes their window I would like fullcalendar to readjust it's width and height to a proper aspect ratio)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's all documented.

Let's see, try something along this lines:

```
//function to calculate window height
function get_calendar_height() {
      return $(window).height() - 30;
}

//attacht resize event to window and set fullcalendar height property
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', get_calendar_height());
    });


    //set fullcalendar height property
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
            //options
            height: get_calendar_height
    });
});
```

Apply similar to width.
Or you could place calendar in div and do manipulations that way.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the help!
p.s. I believe you missed an additional '});' .. but s'all good!

Comment: Some options cannot be set dynamically, such as "handleWindowResize" and "views" (see: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dynamic-options)

Answer (score 10):

For width, we made the calendar flexible, to adjust along with the responsive design, and it worked quite well on larger displays:

```
#calendar {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For any other customization (changing height or default view), use the built-in `windowResize` event for FullCalendar. The downside to the accepted answer is that the function will run WHILE the window is being resized, for every pixel change. Conversely, the `windowResize` event fires AFTER the resizing is complete.

Now, the problem with a responsive calendar is that you're still at the mercy of the table - a terrible place to be on a small mobile screen.

For our project, we choose to force the day view if a user was on a screen smaller than 769px. You can see our method in this example. If it doesn't work for you, at least it will give you some direction on how to implement a solution that does.

```
$(function(){
    var $calendar = $('#calendar');
    $calendar.fullCalendar({
        windowResize: function() {
            var ww = $(window).width();
            var view = (ww <= 768) ? 'basicDay' : 'month';
            var currentView = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
            if(view != currentView){
                $calendar.fullCalendar('changeView',view);
            }
            if(ww <= 768){
                $calendar.find('.fc-header-right .fc-button').hide();
            }else{
                $calendar.find('.fc-header-right .fc-button').show();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the current view is passed in the [`windowResize`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/windowResize) callback.

One could simply manage a responsive behavior with:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    # ...
    windowResize: function (view) {
        var current_view = view['name'];
        var expected_view = $(window).width() > 576 ? 'agendaWeek' : 'agendaDay';
        if (current_view !== expected_view) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', expected_view);
        }
    }
})
```

Also, one should make sure [`handleWindowResize`](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/handleWindowResize) is set to `true` (which is the default)

Answer (score 0):

I googled "responsive calendar", because that is what you wanted I just think you didn't know how to word it. I believe the links I provided you should get you on your way. I am assuming you wanted to do this using javascript/jquery because of your tags. If the links are useful, that is also fine because now you know what to search for, Good Luck!

Responsive Calendar Demos:
http://dbushell.com/demos/calendar/v1_03-01-12.html
http://www.manystrands.com/projects/calendar.html (Changes to agenda view after a certain extent.)

More Info:
http://dbushell.com/2012/01/04/responsive-calendar-demo/

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear. I am working with Adam Shaws fullcalendar jquery plugin.. I've updated my post to clarify!